# How to setup up ATK4.3 on Windows 7 professional SP1

Tags: installation, atk4

I have been trying to set up ATK4.3 on my Win7 machine. The following has been done:

Install WAMP 
Download ATK4.3.0.de, Branch: 4.3, Build: 2014-12-16, ATK4 Revision: 4313 
Unpack zip 
Copy contents of unpacked folder agiletoolkit into wamp/www/my_project 
Execute run.bat

The result being an error message in firefox telling me that the connection has not been successful to localhost:8888.

Accessing the wamp/www/my_project/index.php and logging in with my ATK credentials produces a "jQuery_Chain->exception("js()->..->execute() must be used in response to form submission or AJAX operation only")" error.

I have been looking for answers here: 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/agile-toolkit-devel 
http://book.agiletoolkit.org/index.html

Please help me to finalize the setup of ATK4.3.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I recently setup ATK on Win8.1/WAMP

It works without specifying port on my machine (port must be specified if you use PHP build in web server).

So just try `http://localhost`, or if your ATK is not directly in webroot, try `http://localhost/path/to/atk`

Comment: I moved the contents of the folder www/my_project directly into the www folder. If I run the run.bat there the error message stays the same. What should exactly happen when executing it?  
Accessing http://localhost brings up the "Welcome to Agile Toolkit" page (without any styles and a broken picture link on the top left) but after entering the credentials and submitting the same error as before comes up (jQuery_Chain->exception("js()->..->execute() must be used in response to form submission or AJAX operation only")).

Answer (score 0):

I hope somebody can help you with your question but my suggestion is to use some kind of virtual machine such as [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) with Ubuntu installed. I have OSX which is Unix based operation system but still prefer to use real Linux in virtual machine.

Comment: Installed VirtualBox 4.3.20, created virtual machine running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Installed LAMP, created a folder my_project in var/www/html, used chown to assign my user to be the owner of the folder, copied the ATK files into that folder.  
Started apache, ran run.sh, terminal telling me that development server has started & is listening on localhost:8888. Localhost gives me the following error: *Application Error: Notice: [/var/www/html/fin_cockpit/vendor/atk4/atk4/lib/Controller/Data/<b>RESTful.php</b>:32]Use of undefined constant CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER - assumed 'CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER'*

Comment: Looks like you didn't install cURL or curl extension for php.

Comment: One *sudo apt-get install php5-curl* later I *sudo service apache2 start* and *./run.sh*. Then I again called up http://localhost which then gave me a fully layouted login screen. Providing my credentials and removing one permission issue made the install go through and I had my sandbox up and running - thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue so I checked the Apache error log (`C:\wamp\logs\apache_error.log`) and I saw this error:

```
C:/wamp/www/agiletoolkit/vendor/atk4/atk4/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine'
```

So I renamed the `.htaccess` file to `nope.htaccess` (obviously could be anything or even just delete it) and it worked for me.